# What's wrong with my MIPS code about finding fibonacci number?

Tags: c, assembly, mips

I have a C code as following:

```
int fibonacci(int n){
    int a, b, c;
    int i;

    a = 1;
    b = 1;
    c = 2;

    if(n == 1)  return 1;
    else if(n == 2) return 1;
    else if(n == 3) return 2;

    for(i = 3; i < n; i++){
        a = b;
        b = c;
        c = a + b;
    }

    return c;
}
```

And I compile this code like this.

```
    addi    $sp, $sp, -32   
    sw  $t0, 28($sp)
    sw  $t1, 24($sp)
    sw  $t2, 20($sp)
    sw  $t3, 16($sp)
    li  $t0, 1
    li  $t1, 1
    li  $t2, 2
    li  $t3, 3      
    move    $t4, $a0
    beq $a0, 1, FIRSTL
    beq $a0, 1, SECONDL
    beq $a0, 2, THIRDL

FIRSTL:

    li  $v0, 1
    j   FOR

SECONDL:

    li  $v0, 1
    j   FOR
THIRDL:

    li  $v0, 2
    j   FOR
FOR:

    beq $t3, $a0, ENDL
    addi    $t1, $t1, 1
    j   FOR
    move    $s0, $s1
    move    $s1, $s2
    add $s2, $s1, $s0

ENDL:

    lw  $t1, 16($sp)
    lw  $s2, 20($sp)    
    lw  $s1, 24($sp)
    lw  $s0, 28($sp)
    addi    $sp, $sp, -32
    add     $v1, $0, $s2
```

It just shows 0th Fibonacci and the other's Fibonacci has never happened.
What's wrong with my Mips code?  I'm very confusing.

Comment: I don't see a problem with your C or MIPs code. Can you explain a bit please? Which input creates an incorrect output?

Comment: How did you compile the code? If you did that manually, e.g. as a homework assignment, I am impressed (no sarcasm). But if not, why did you provide the assembler code? Please create an MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. And, a more generic version of @Arash s comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You have `j   FOR` before the 2x `move` and the `add $s2, $s1, $s0` instructions that actually implement the Fibonacci calculation.

So the logic in your asm loop matches this C:

```
 do{                     // FOR:
     if (i == n) break;  //   beq
     i++;                //   add 1
 }while(true);           //   j FOR

 a = b;
 b = c;
 c = a + b;
ENDL:
 // restore some registers that you didn't need to save/restore, just clobber $t regs.
 // missing jr $ra  to actually return
```

**Put the work inside the loop.**